# Bootstrap vertical align middle div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to col-6 one has a image and one has text.
I need go get the text in the center off the image.

this is the html code.
Thanks Dan

```html
 <div class="row_inner_wrapper  clearfix">
  <div class="row_inner row_center_content clearfix">
   <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
     <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div class="row_inner_wrapper clearfix">
        <div><h2 class="text-center">~ 1995 – סודות ההצלחה ~</h2></div>
     </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
     <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey">
         <img src="jjjj.coo.com">
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there are multiple ways and easier ways to do this, check this link https://css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/

Answer (score 0):

please check the below edited snippet.

```css
.row_inner_wrapper {text-align:center;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="row_inner_wrapper  clearfix">
  <div class="row_inner row_center_content clearfix">
   <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
     <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div class="row_inner_wrapper clearfix">
        <div><h2 class="text-center">~ 1995 – סודות ההצלחה ~</h2></div>
     </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
     <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey">
         <img src="jjjj.coo.com">
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```